# JavaScript Parsing array and getting the unique value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array:

```
    array-1:

        Array[11]
        0:"265"
        1:"text-success"
        2:"51"
        3:"text-warning"
        4:"16"
        5:"text-warning"
        6:"35"
        7:"text-warning"
        8:"38"
        9:"text-warning"
        10:"106"

    array-2:
        Array[11]
        0:"265"
        1:"text-success"
        2:"51"
        3:"text-warning"
        4:"16"
        5:"text-warning"
        6:"35"
        7:"text-success"
        8:"38"
        9:"text-warning"
        10:"106"

   array-3:
        Array[11]
        0:"265"
        1:"muted"
        2:"51"
        3:"text-warning"
        4:"16"
        5:"text-warning"
        6:"35"
        7:"text-success"
        8:"38"
        9:"text-warning"
        10:"106"

    array-4:
        Array[11]
        0:"265"
        1:"text-warning"
        2:"51"
        3:"text-warning"
        4:"16"
        5:"muted"
        6:"35"
        7:"text-warning"
        8:"38"
        9:"text-warning"
        10:"106"
```

1st one will return FALSE because both exist "text-success"-twice AND "muted"-once

2nd one will return TRUE because it exist ONCE "text-success"

3rd one will return FALSE because both exist "text-success" AND "muted"

4th one will return TRUE because it exist ONCE "muted"

I need to parse the array and get the result:

```
array-1:

    Array[11]
        0:"265"
        1:"text-success"
        2:"51"

array-2: Null

array-3: Null

array-4:

    Array[11]
        0:"265"
        1:"muted"
        2:"16"
```

so far I have this:

```
function singles( array) {
    for( var index = 0, single = []; index < array.length; index++ ) { 
        if(array[index] == "text-success" || array[index] == "muted") {
            single.push(array[index]);
        }
    }
    return single;
};
```

Please help anyone?

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? This screams "ugly workaround-hack" to me.

Comment: @TomLord I am tring to parse array in Javascript

Comment: But... **Why?** What **problem** are you trying to solve?

Comment: That's not an Array but an object containing 4 sub-Arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether you have an object that contains multiple arrays, or just a standard one-dimensional array for which you've given several possible examples, but assuming the latter I think this is what you're looking for:

```js
function singles(array) {
  var foundIndex = -1;
      
  for(var index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if(array[index] === "text-success" || array[index] === "muted") {
      if (foundIndex != -1) {
        // we've found two, so...
        return null;
      }
      foundIndex = index;
    }
  }
  if (foundIndex != -1) {
    return [ array[0], array[foundIndex], array[foundIndex+1] ];
  }
  return "Some default value for when it wasn't found at all";
}

console.log(singles(["532","text-warning","51","text-warning","16","muted","35","text-warning","38","text-warning","106"]));
console.log(singles(["533","text-warning","51","text-warning","16","muted","35","text-success","38","text-warning","106"]));
```

This loops through the input `array`. The first time `"text-success"` or `"muted"` is found its index is stored in `foundIndex`.

If `"text-success"` or `"muted"` is found a second time we immediately return `null`.

If we get to the end of the loop then we know we found `"text-success"` or `"muted"` either once or not at all. If it was found once we return an array of three elements included the first item in the input array, the value of `"text-success"` or `"muted"`, and then the item that immediately followed that text in the array.

(Note: in your example output from Array 1 you returned the value *after* the matched text, but in your example output from Array 4 you returned the value *before* the matched text. I don't know which one you really want, but you can easily modify my function to do one or the other.)

You didn't say what you wanted to return if `"text-success"` or `"muted"` wasn't present in the array, so I've just returned a place-holder string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if it exists `"text-success"` or `"muted"` once in the array, use this function, it will return a boolean:

```
function singles(array) {
    var single = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === "text-success" || array[i] === "muted") {
            if (single) {
                return false;
            }
            single = true;
        }
    }
    return single;
}
```

If you want to return the unique value among `"text-success"` or `"muted"`, use the following function. It will return the unique value, or `null` otherwise:

```
function singles(array) {
    var single = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === "text-success" || array[i] === "muted") {
            if (single) {
                return null;
            }
            single = array[i];
        }
    }
    return single;
}
```

If you need the code of the corresponding value, use this:

```
function singles(array) {
    var single = null;
    for (var i = 1; i < array.length; i += 2) {
        if (array[i] === "text-success" || array[i] === "muted") {
            if (single) {
                return null;
            }
            single = array[i - 1];
        }
    }
    return single;
}
```

Comment: Array[11]
        0:"265"
        1:"text-success"
        2:"51"

Comment: Do I need to group them

Comment: @TanvirAlam I added the code to my answer to get the identifier of the unique value.

Comment: @TanvirAlam Oops sorry, replaced `i *= 2` by `i += 2`