# Javascript Object array parsing issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, unique

I have the following object in Javascript:

```
Array[11]
0:"532"
1:"text-warning"
2:"51"
3:"text-warning"
4:"16"
5:"muted"
6:"35"
7:"text-warning"
8:"38"
9:"text-warning"
10:"106"

Array[11]
0:"533"
1:"text-warning"
2:"51"
3:"text-warning"
4:"16"
5:"muted"
6:"35"
7:"text-success"
8:"38"
9:"text-warning"
10:"106"

Array[11]
0:"534"
1:"text-warning"
2:"51"
3:"text-warning"
4:"16"
5:"text-warning"
6:"35"
7:"text-success"
8:"38"
9:"text-warning"
10:"106"
```

I would like to parse it and find if two value exist only once within this array.

Example: "text-success" OR "muted" if EXIST ONCE return the array

if it EXIST twice return null

if TRUE return the corresponding id

In the above example:

1st Array: is TRUE

```
Array[11]
0:"532"
1:"muted"
2:"35"
```

2nd one is FALSE because its exist twice

3rd one: is also TRUE

```
Array[11]
0:"534"
1:"text-success"
2:"38"
```

I have been trying this past few days was not successful

I have the following JQUERY: but it only gets the Unique value but discard the others:

I need the first id and the corresponding id as well:

```
Array[11]
0:"534" -> main id (needed)
1:"text-success"
2:"38" ->  company id (needed)



function singles( array) {
    for( var index = 0, single = []; index < array.length; index++ ) { 

        if(array[index] == "text-success" || array[index] == "muted") {
            single.push(array[index]);
        }
    }
    return single;
};
```

The result or the output which is required:

```
  Array[11]
    0:"532",
    1:"muted",
    2:"35",
```

The first value is the Main ID, 
the 2nd value is the UNIQUE and 
the 3rd value is the corresponding ID for the unique value.

Comment: Where is your jQuery?

Comment: please add the object/array as text literal.

Comment: @choz it is there, please have a look

Comment: @NinaScholz what do u mean?

Comment: something like `var o = { a: "foo", b: 42, c: {} };`.

Comment: @NinaScholz do u have any solution? I am going creazy

Comment: *"if it EXIST twice return null and also return the corresponding id"* - What do you mean *and also* return? A function can only return one "thing", though that thing can be an array or object. What *exactly* is the desired output?

Comment: @nnnnnn I corrected it. the output/results is also given

Comment: @NinaScholz I have manually created the object, if generated it gives 1000 objects.

Comment: @NinaScholz what I did is counsol.log

Comment: The first part of your question says that you want to return either the whole array or null depending on how many matches, so that would involve simply changing your return statement to something like `return single.length === 1 ? array : null;`.

Comment: @nnnnnn the function works but it doesn't return the first id and the corresponding id.

Comment: You're really not helping to make this any clearer: your question has contradictory requirements, where first you say you want to return "the array", but then later you say you want to return "the first id and the corresponding id" but your array has about six different ids in it - so which is "first", and which is "corresponding"? Please [edit] your question to show an example of the desired return format from the function, and the input the would lead to that output.

Comment: @nnnnnn sorry anout it, I wrote it in hurry. I edited it and put the result I need below. please have look

Comment: OK, I've posted an answer. In any future questions please do what Nina asked and post your input in the format `["532","text-warning","51","text-warning","16","muted","35","text-warning","38","text-warning","106"]` rather than just dumping whatever was logged to the console.

Comment: why does the answer of the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567697/javascript-parsing-array-and-getting-the-unique-value does not work for you? how is this question different from the other?

Comment: @NinaScholz - Thanks for the duplicate link, I've deleted my answer and posted it in that other question. Unfortunately SO won't let me close this one as a duplicate because back before I figured out what the OP wants (or what I think they want) I'd already voted to close this as unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve:

> - transform Object to Array
> - Check duplicated element then pass
> - unique element push into new array

```
var obj = {
0:"532",
1:"text-warning",
2:"51",
3:"text-warning",
4:"16",
5:"muted",
6:"35",
7:"text-warning",
8:"38",
9:"text-warning",
10:"106"
};


function restUnique(obj){
 var mix = [];
 var output= [];
 Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {

    mix[key]=obj[key];

 });

 for(var i in mix){
  fb=mix.indexOf(mix[i]);
  fa=mix.lastIndexOf(mix[i]);
  if(fb===fa){output.push(mix[i]);}
 }
return output;
}
// usage example:
restUnique(obj); // output : 532,51,16,muted,35,38,106
```